# Is a Siemens star, printed with laser printer, suficiant for sharpness testing?

Tags: focus, focus-adjust, back-focus

I have a Samsung SCX-4600 and I decided to make a Siemens star out of it using an A4 paper with vector to very high resolution PNG illustrations.

Is it an decent choice? How will it compare to a genuine focus chart of it? I want to use it for sharpness testing with my DSLR.

I also have access to antique KY 19E and Sony UVW100 camcorders with Canon YH13X7.5 lenses. Would my makeshift Siemens star also be adequate for back focus?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If looking for metrics, there are companies like DXOMark that do very professional testing for this and more and list those metrics. However, sharpness tests aren't everything. Beautiful photos have been taken with lens and camera combos measuring 3/10 on their sharpness charts and absolute garbage has been shot with 10/10 lenses. What problem are you trying to solve with all of this?

Comment: @Hueco to be honest I want to use these classic camcorders while using them on Pvm CRTs. I also want to know how an expensive test card compares to a home made one.

Comment: *"I want to use these classic camcorders while using them on Pvm CRTs"* -- cool, what's your concern/question about this setup or the process in doing so? "*I also want to know how an expensive test card compares to a home made one"* -- this seems unanswerable. While a pro card's exact structure is known...your homemade one is not, so how can they be compared theoretically? Best you could do is get ahold of a legit test card and compare them side by side.

Comment: What is considered sufficient by one user may or may not be sufficient for another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only testing for relative sharpness and focus accuracy then you don't really need a chart at all. You only need a target/subject of good contrast with fine enough details to judge sharp/unsharp. And something with consistent/repeating details that transitions near-far for judging front/back focus (i.e. a ruler placed at ~45* adjacent to your target).

If you want quantifiable/reliable test data, then there is a lot more to it than just "which chart do I use." And quite probably a home printed test chart would be problematic.